# Java Parallel Stream always log same threadID

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

I'm using parallel stream on a List. I suppose it will use WorkJoinPool to spawn multiple work threads, somehow there's only one thread all the time according to the log:

```
14:32:14.561 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] INFO from parent_thread
14:32:15.071 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] INFO from first_element_execution
14:32:15.228 [http-nio-8080-exec-146] INFO from second_element_execution
... and so on.
```

Here's the short version of my code:

```
List<String> myList = ...;
myList.parallelStream().forEach( // Do something and slf4j.log it );
```

**[EDITED]**
I've tried some very simple code on my local machine and it does spawn multiple threads. Unfortunately I couldn't run the production code neither on my local nor some other environment..

Why doesn't my parallelStream use WorkJoinPool to spawn multiple threads?

Thank you!

Comment: Parallel stream doesn't spawn threads - it uses either the common ForkJoinThreadPool, or (if the current thread is itself in a fork-join pool) - the current thread pool.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov yes you are absolutely right. Let me re-phase my question.

Comment: `List` by itself is just an interface – what's the actual implementation of your `List`?

Comment: @kaan It's an ArrayList. FYI, The code only reads the list.

Comment: @Top.Deck, I guess the work queue for your current nio thread pool is empty, and current thread can steal all the work for itself. Try sleeping in subtasks, maybe that'll cause other threads to come out (assuming there's not a single thread in that pool).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov the nio thread pool should be busy because this piece of code is actually in a doPost(). Server keeps receiving requests all the time.

Comment: @Top.Deck. If pool is so busy that no other thread steals the task (because they have their own and never go looking to steal), then it might also so happen that all tasks for a specific requests are processed on the same thread.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov that’s one possibility. But actually server is not overloaded. Its status is fine.

Comment: @Top.Deck server should not necessarily be overloaded. ForkJoinPool by default has numCPUs - 1 threads. So it might happen that when you call `parallelStream()` only one thread is available at that pool. You can try to generate thread dump if you need more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how many cores your CPU on production has. You are using common ForkJoinPool which is initialised by expression: number of available processors - 1. So probably this thread pool has only 1 thread.

Comment: Since I don't have the access to production server, I won't be able to run jstack to check the threads. Still, I agree with you.